# Is there a way to add dropbox chooser or google drive picker into the publish page?

Tags: add-on, fieldtype

I've been using expression engine for 5 years now, but I am new to this forum, so hi everyone!

I was wondering if there is a way to use the dropbox chooser and/or google drive features inside the publish page of expression engine.

Had looked into devot-ee, but so far theres nothing for google, and for dropbox there is an addon but only to display dropbox files.

This will be really useful. I am needing this functionality currently for a site I am building.

Please let me know, if someone have a hint or have heard of something in this regard.

Thanks for your time

Regards

-Manuel

Comment: i guess that would require a custom addon

Comment: Hello Yuri, Thanks for popping in. Yes, but I thought there was maybe something out there some of you guys might already be using. I ll try to figure out how to build a custom app then. Thanks

Comment: Found this lurking around:

Comment: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~johnathb/misc/gpicker.html

Comment: Maybe there is a way to make that work with ee?

Answer (score 2):

I've put together [dropbox_chooser](https://github.com/simonjob/dropbox_chooser) which is a fieldtype. At the moment, it opens the Dropbox Chooser and allows you to pick a single file (whilst multiselect can work, I'm not sure how to output multiple links individually in a template).

You will need an App Key from Dropbox.

I'm no developer, but I needed this functionality.